# How to render React component inside JSF using javascript chunks?

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, jsf, primefaces

I have interesting case where I have to put React component inside JSF part of business application. I tried to achieve that with `<h:outputScipt>` but without success.

I imported chunks from react component and put them like here:

[image]

Then I used `<h:outputScript/>` like this:

```
<ui:composition template="/templates/tempMain.xhtml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <ui:define name="content">
        <h:form id="AdditionalServiceTemplatesForm">
            <p:panel id="additionalServiceTemplatesPanel">
                <div id="ComponentName" style="background-color: white" class="container"></div>
                    <h:outputScript library="js" name="19.649a5d09.chunk.js"/>
                    <h:outputScript library="js" name="runtime-main.d6107f88.js"/>
                    <h:outputScript library="js" name="main.d73a6ff5.chunk.js"/>
                    <h:outputScript library="js" name="hello.js"/>
                <h:form>
                    <h:commandButton onclick = "showMessage();" />
                </h:form>
            </p:panel>
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Normal javascript script hello.js (not chunk) is visible and is working but react component from chunks is not rendered. All I've got is empty jsf container.

Additionaly there is information in the console:
[image]

Additionaly I tried to change relative paths in chunks from static/js to "resources/js" and "javax.faces.resource/js" and without any path. Nothing is working.

After compilation, sources looks like this:

[image]

Comment: `library="js"` is utterly wrong. Use `name="js/hello.js"` etc and retry. Note that you can also just use plain HTML `<script src>` in JSF.

Comment: @BalusC but hello.js was working that way, but the rest of chunks are not. Anyway I tried with name="js/..." and same result, hello is working and chunks are not rendered.

Comment: Have you tried `<script src=…`?

Comment: If you don't need to modify the sources of the react component in any dynamic way, but they would work as static resources, I even would prefer the plain `<script src=...>` approach anyways, as then only the browser has to care for fetching the JS-files (which he would have to do anyways).

Comment: @cyberbrain you mean that I should use <script scr=...> for every chunk or just for some of them (like main or runtime-main)?

Comment: tbh I don't kno w about the react-part of this question, so as I think that the react component is created once (at compile time and not at runtime), the same static include should be used as in a static web page, but I don't know, how to exactly do that. Actually I think by the file structure, that you are handling more than just a single react component.

Comment: I assume we are talking about a complete application in react? Then it won't work like that. At a minimum, you need to remember that the render goes to <div id='root'>. We need specifics to give an exact answer, but try to insert not js but root, connect the scripts below. Try this in html to see the errors. As for the source map - do not generate it, then it will not be needed, or remove links to it at the end of js files.